# PHPEXCEL use fromArray fill value, rows hidden?

Tags: phpexcel

My array data:

```
1801,1802,1806,1896,1896,1896
2,51,89,632,454,31
null,7,13,36,43,1
1,12,12,33,26,5
null,3,4,7,6,null
null,null,null,null,null,null
1,15,14,49,34,3
null,1,null,2,3,1
null,17,20,37,54,1
null,3,1,3,3,null
null,32,64,190,163,4
null,null,null,1,null,null
```

`$book->fromArray($tmp, null, 'B6');` 
//B-D6 is ok

`$book->fromArray($tmp, null, 'E6');` 
//>=E6,  6-11 rows were hidden, canceled hidden fail,Like there is no data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1iSS.jpg)

Comment: `fromArray()` will not magically hide any rows, or change their visibility; so what else is your code doing? Or are those rows already hidden in a template that you're loading (`fromArray()` 
 won't "unhide" rows either)?

Comment: thanks Mark Baker, the problem is solved. in the template,table header has filter condition. this is my fault.